# How can I get this Rijndael managed encryption to work on iOS?

Tags: c#, ios, encryption

I need encrypt and decrypt between an iPhone application and a C# one, where Rijndael managed encryption is used. The following is the code I have for doing this in C#, but I'm trying to reimplement this in Objective-C:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace RijndaelManagedEncryption
{

public class RijndaelManagedEncryption
{
    #region Consts
    /// <summary>
    /// Change the Inputkey GUID when you use this code in your own program.
    /// Keep this inputkey very safe and prevent someone from decoding it some way!!
    /// </summary>
    internal const string Inputkey = "560A18CD-6346-4CF0-A2E8-671F9B6B9EA9";
    #endregion

    #region Rijndael Encryption

    /// <summary>
    /// Encrypt the given text and give the byte array back as a BASE64 string
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="text" />The text to encrypt
    /// <param name="salt" />The pasword salt
    /// <returns>The encrypted text</returns>
    public static string EncryptRijndael(string text, string salt)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(text))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("text");

        var aesAlg = NewRijndaelManaged(salt);

        var encryptor = aesAlg.CreateEncryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
        var msEncrypt = new MemoryStream();
        using (var csEncrypt = new CryptoStream(msEncrypt, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        using (var swEncrypt = new StreamWriter(csEncrypt))
        {
            swEncrypt.Write(text);
        }

        return Convert.ToBase64String(msEncrypt.ToArray());
    }
    #endregion

    #region Rijndael Dycryption
    /// <summary>
    /// Checks if a string is base64 encoded
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="base64String" />The base64 encoded string
    /// <returns>
    public static bool IsBase64String(string base64String)
    {
        base64String = base64String.Trim();
        return (base64String.Length%4 == 0) &&
               Regex.IsMatch(base64String, @"^[a-zA-Z0-9\+/]*={0,3}$", RegexOptions.None);

    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Decrypts the given text
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="cipherText" />The encrypted BASE64 text
    /// <param name="salt" />The pasword salt
    /// <returns>De gedecrypte text</returns>
    public static string DecryptRijndael(string cipherText, string salt)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(cipherText))
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cipherText");

        if (!IsBase64String(cipherText))
            throw new Exception("The cipherText input parameter is not base64 encoded");

        string text;

        var aesAlg = NewRijndaelManaged(salt);
        var decryptor = aesAlg.CreateDecryptor(aesAlg.Key, aesAlg.IV);
        var cipher = Convert.FromBase64String(cipherText);

        using (var msDecrypt = new MemoryStream(cipher))
        {
            using (var csDecrypt = new CryptoStream(msDecrypt, decryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Read))
            {
                using (var srDecrypt = new StreamReader(csDecrypt))
                {
                    text = srDecrypt.ReadToEnd();
                }
            }
        }
        return text;
    }
    #endregion

    #region NewRijndaelManaged
    /// <summary>
    /// Create a new RijndaelManaged class and initialize it
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="salt" />The pasword salt
    /// <returns>
    private static RijndaelManaged NewRijndaelManaged(string salt)
    {
        if (salt == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("salt");
        var saltBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(salt);
        var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(Inputkey, saltBytes);

        var aesAlg = new RijndaelManaged();
        aesAlg.Key = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.KeySize / 8);
        aesAlg.IV = key.GetBytes(aesAlg.BlockSize / 8);

        return aesAlg;
    }
    #endregion
}
```

}

The one issue that is difficult is how to replace `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` with `PBKDF2`. Although both are essentially the same two APIs are different. The two main issues are the iteration count and obtaining the `iv`.

My question then is: What iteration should be used and how to obtain an `iv`?

Comment: @Andrew Barber Gee, single handily closing this question seems a little heavy handed. With a few comments this could have been a good question. In particular how to use PBKDF2 to replace Rfc2898DeriveBytes is interesting. I hope this is not the new SO!

Comment: @Zaph Comments are still possible, as is editing the question to a point where it can be reopened. As the question stands, it deserves to be closed. It's simply not good enough.

Comment: @Bart I did comment, have edited the question, voted to re-open and flagged the question for moderator attention.

Comment: @Zaph - I have to agree with Andrew, that as originally phrased, this was not an acceptable question. It was asking for us to rewrite an entire block of C# code. It still needed a lot more editing, but I've done my best to build on your edit (which was a question not present in the original incarnation here) to craft something that we can answer. I've reopened as a result, but I think the proper action was taken to begin with.

Comment: @Brad Thanks for re-opening this question! I agree the original question was overly broad and asked for to much. I disagree with a moderator closing where there had not been any comments or other close votes. Encryption is difficult for most people. Overall I am dismayed by the number of question down votes and close votes, some times so quickly that the OP does not have a chance to answer comments and/or update the question. Interestingly, I posted on meta about this, lot's of comments, then closed, no problem. Now it has been re-opened--this is just getting crazy!

Comment: Can someone post an example of the result from `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, with inputs for password and salt along with the outputs key and iv as per the question? That would give me something to compare against (I don't have a C# compiler).

Comment: @Zaph - Placing a question on hold is merely an indication that it needs some work, not a final state for the question. Once edited, it's immediately placed in the reopen queue for reevaluation. Even a moderator's vote can be overruled by the community if it was wrong or the question was significantly improved.

Comment: @Zaph You may use any PBKDF2 implementation to generate such a result, as long as you keep to UTF-8 to encode the password (or you could use the `byte[]` version of `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` of course). A quick Google search: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc6070.txt . To my knowledge the MS version does not have any mistakes (as `PasswordDeriveBytes` **does** have).

Comment: @owlstead The issue is that Rfc2898DeriveBytes allows for multiple `GetBytes()` and PBKDF2 does not. The second `GetBytes()` gets a value for the iv, that is the issue that needs to resolved.

Comment: PBKDF2 does allow for output larger than the hash size and `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` does behave correctly when asked for more bytes (this is where `PasswordDeriveBytes` screws up badly); it is the same as asking for both the bytes of the key and the IV at the same time. So check the next to last vector with 25 bytes output in the RFC. Actually it is more secure and, well, more accurate to put the output of the PBKDF through a KBKDF to derive key and IV, but that's getting a bit too technical I suppose.